# Dual Core, Core 2 Duo, Core i Series

Tags: cpu, threads

How does **Dual Core**, **Core 2 Duo**, **Core i Series** processors executes
(1) process without threads
(2) process with threads

Actually I want to know how these processors distribute a **single process (without and with threads)** among their **Cores** or **CPUs** (as the case may be)? Its a bit confusing to me.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That depends 100% on the OS and the BIOS.  If you run an old OS that has no support for multiple logical processors, they'll all run on the primary thread of the primary core of the primary CPU.  If the OS and BIOS support it, the OS should try to balance all the processes and the threads among all the CPUs.

Comment: It's not always up to the OS to balance processes and threads (some special purpose systems do this differently), but in any case it's software (either OS or applications) that distribute tasks over the different cores/CPUs.